# PYTHON CSV File Upload - WebUI -> Lambda ->S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to the AWS Lambda. i have a requirement like upload csv file to S3 through Lambda.
this is web based application. from UI User will upload the CSV File and submit. this request should be handled by Lambda function(Python) and upload the csv content to S3 Bucket.

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use lambda to upload to S3 you'll need to use API Gateway and map the endpoint to Lambda.

An easier way is to upload directly to S3, bypassing lambda. You should use [presigned urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) to do the upload.